# UIImage Saving issue in iOS7 : Blending issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage

Here is screenshot from simulator and saved image:

[image]

Code :

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);

[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage *screenshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

//guru - just for simulator
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Image.png"];

[UIImagePNGRepresentation(screenshotImage) writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
//end guru

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screenshotImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

How can I fix this problem ? Works good when I build it with Xcode4_iOS6, but not with Xcode5_iOS7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix it in this way:

```
    if([self IS_IOS_7])
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, TRUE, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
    }
    else
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
    }


    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage *screenshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screenshotImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

iOS7 Check:

```
-(bool)IS_IOS_7
{
    NSString *currOsVersion = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];

    float sysver = [currOsVersion floatValue] ;

    if(sysver >=7.0f)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Is `IS_IOS_7` really necessary?  You could use `if (UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions != NULL)` to take advantage of the method on all OS versions that support it.